# What factors into the score in Classic Mode?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've been playing for a week and I can't seem to figure out if there is anything to the scoring in classic mode besides damage done, kills, and deaths. I know in past games there were bonuses for doing special things like not using items or finishing at a certain time.

What factors into the score in Classic Mode besides damage done, kills, and deaths?

Comment: The difficulty level also has a big impact on your score.

Comment: I would guess it's similar to older games (as you mention), they just don't show the score screen this time. I would propose we wait until the wiiu version is out and see if anything changes.

Comment: By "score" do you mean GSP?

Comment: @Bakon maybe. What I'm referring to is the score shown after you beat a stage in classic mode.  I'm not sure if there is another name for it.